# Activity not shown through LockScreen

Tags: android

I am trying to show an Activity through a Lockscreen.
This is the second one in my app, the first one actually works without any problem.
I am using a wakelock :

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    //mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

and I am using the expected code within the activity itself

```
"getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I even tried this option :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
    lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD;
    lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON;
    lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

The big difference between the two activities is when they are shown.
The first one (the one thats's working) reacts on the android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED broadcast, whilst the second one on the Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED broadcast.

Why wouldn't the second one work ? The lockscreen is not removed to show my activity, if I actually swipe the lockscreen away my activity is showing right beneath it.
Might it be that the plugging power in actually is not interceptable ?

/EDIT :

I did discover the difference between the two activities : 
the one who does not work actually has a Theme based on the Dialog Theme.

```
<style name="ThemeWithCorners" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
```

If I remove this it works just fine, so now the question is how do I get a Dialog-Theme based activity to behave in the same manner ???

/EDIT2:
After some more googling and searching I found this piece of code that works :

```
KeyguardManager keyMgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyLock = keyMgr.newKeyguardLock(TAG);
    keyLock.disableKeyguard();
```

The bad thing is that the newKeyguardLock() method has been deprecated. So it might not work anymore in future releases (tested on 4.1.2).
If anyone knows the right way to accompish this same feat ?

Comment: If you have `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` in a BroadcastReceiver, it should work. If the lock screen is not dismissed, maybe because it's pin or password protected.

Comment: Nope there is no other protection.
I did discover the difference between the two activities : the one who does not work actually has a Theme based on the Dialog Theme. If I remove this it works just fine, so now the question is how do I get a Dialog-Theme based activity to behave in the same manner ???

Comment: You may need to ask another question as per SO rules.

Comment: Should I ask a completely new quiestion or simply edit this one, including the title ?

Comment: Please ask another question.